# Prevent view from overflowing in both directions

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build a user-expandable view that will show more of its content by increasing its height. To accomplish this I will add `.clipped()` so that the content shown out of its bounds will be hidden, just like you would add `overflow: hidden;` in CSS.

However, it seems like by default `VStack` is centering its children, so when the height is smaller than the sum of the children's height, they overflow in both the top and the bottom.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```swift
struct ExandableView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .frame(height: 90)
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

[image: Example of the code above being run]

Is there any way to make it behave so that the red item (the first) is always inside the blue container and the children can only overflow from the bottom?

Comment: You can do something like this ```.frame(height: 90, alignment: isExpand ? .top : .center)```

Comment: In my opinion the best approach to create an expandable view in SwiftUI is to work with if-Statements in order to show and hide the content instead of clipping the view. If that idea fits your use case I can provide you a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Adrian Unfortunately I think that wouldn't work. I'm trying to build a UI like Apple Map's bottom sheet, so the visibility of the children is not a true/false, but a progressive animation while the user drags the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change frame alignment according to ExandableView. like this

```
struct ExandableView: View {
    var body: some View {
       // Other VStack code
        }
        .frame(height: 90, alignment: isExpand ? .top : .center) //<--Here
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```